# how can i refence a c++ method outside?

Tags: c++, qt

say , i have some classes, `Music`, `Video`, `Photo`, and have a class named `Control`, `Control` has a method, `centerlcall(char* fuction_name,char* json_para)`, the `fuction_name` could be one of the `Music`, `Video`, `Photo`'s member methods. so, i want call the member method from `Control`'s `centercall` function.

```
class Contact {
 pubilc:
 Contact();
 void getallcontact(char* data);
 void changeContact(char* data);
 void addacontact(char* data);
};

class Music {
 public :
 Music();
 void getMusic(char* data);
 void addMusic(char* data);
 void playMusic(char* data);
}

class Video {
 public:
 Video();
 void getVideo(char* data);
 void addVideo(char* data);
}

class Photo {
 public:
 photo();
 void getPhoto(char* data);
}

class Control {
   public:
   Control();
   centerlcall(char* fuction_name,char* json_para){
      //check function_name is in video ,photo,music ,if in , call the method . 
   }
}
```

how could i do it? is it qt helpfull?

which i want is not let usr call Music's getMusic dirctly or other else , but call centercall,and tell centercall what method he want call , it's something like ajax .

Comment: What are you expecting to happen when, say, you call `getMusic`?

Comment: Please use proper punctuation, that text is very difficult to read.

Comment: I think the commas are on sale

Comment: @mike where are Video, Photo... stored?

Comment: if you want , you could store it in Control .

Comment: You don't seem to have a way of identifying which instance whould handle the call. Unless it would make sense for you to have several instances of each class, it would be much easier to use free functions instead.

Answer (score 3):

Enough with function pointers! Have it the object oriented way!

```
class Stuff {
public:
   virtual ~Stuff();

   virtual void get(char* data) = 0;
};


class Music : public Stuff{
   public :
      Music();
      void get(char* data);
}

class Video : public Stuff {
   public:
      Video();
      void get(char* data);
}

class Photo : public Stuff {
   public:
      Photo();
      void get(char* data);
}



class Control {
   public:
      Control();
      void centerlcall(Stuff* hisStuff, char* json_para){
          hisStuff->get(/* whatever */);
      }
}
```

Beautiful.

---

*"thanks , i want use something like the jni , every class like music have a regist method to regist's exported method to Control , but i don't know how to write it ."*

```
class Control {
   public:
      Control();
      void centerlcall(Stuff* hisStuff, char* json_para){
          hisStuff->get(/* whatever */);
      }

      void registerStuff (Stuff* hisStuff) {  // <- It's that easy!
         // push it to a vector or a list or whatever data collection you want
      }
}
```

Comment: no ,  i will not change the fucntion name , and it is just a sample , different classs will have different method.

Comment: @mike Have it your way then.

Comment: thanks , i want use something like the jni , every class like music have a regist method to regist's exported method to Control , but i don't know how to write it .

Comment: @mike You're welcome. And remember: whenever you can, do it the OO way!

Comment: that's terrible advice. OO is just one possible concept that fits a set of problems, there are enough programming paradigms besides OO that provide a much better match to a very wide range of problems.

Comment: hi , garcia , i have edited my code in the question , could i wirte code like registerStuff using a base class ?

Comment: @mike Stuff is your base class for that.

Answer (score 1):

As the classes have nothing in common you have to save the functions you want to call somewhere. Note that C++ does not do this for you, there is no metadata like function names stored, you have to do this yourself, e.g.:

```
class Control {
   std::unordered_map<std::string,std::function<void(char*)>> functions;
   public:
   Control();
   centerlcall(char* fuction_name,char* json_para){
      functions[function_name](json_para);
   }
}
```

Of course you still have to add the relevant functions to the map, maybe you want the key not be function name but object name + function name, ... . Or instead of reinventing the wheel, you can use an event/signals library which should provide you with the appropriate framework to do this.

unrelated: please don't use things like `char*`, use `std::string` instead.

Comment: yes , i want use something like this , but could i add a c++'s method to  map ?

Comment: Yes you can, just read up a bit about [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) and [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) ;). Note that if you can't use C++11 almost all of this is available in boost.